# What would be in the Kernel of a Dequantization Map?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantization, wigner-transform

Consider forming a symplectic map between all the Hamiltonians on Hilbert Space and all the Hamiltonians on Phase Space. (I understand that taking the Converse of the Groenewold Van-Hove Theorem this is somewhat non-sensical but bear with me)

What would be in the Kernel of such a map ?

Can you even form a homomorphism between the operators in hilbert space and those in phase space ?

Comment: Prof @CosmasZachos, what would be found in the Kernel of a Wigner map ?

Comment: Are you thinking of the Stratanovich kernel as per https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0611194 (which contains the kernel for both qp and spin cases) or http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/50/32/323001/meta?

Comment: @zerothehero thank you for bringing these to my attention

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9809052.pdf this paper seems to feature what I had in mind

Comment: Beware: there is problem with parameter counting in Brif+Mann.  In particular, the number of angles in their harmonic functions is not always even (it's 5 for SU3 if I remember well) and greater than the number in the appropriate coset space.   See Beg&Ruegg J.Math.Phys vol. 6 (1965) 677 for harmonic functions on SU3, which they have depending on 5 parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The c-number phase-space kernel $g(x,p)$ of any Hilbert-space operator   ${\mathfrak G}({\mathfrak x},{\mathfrak p})$ is specified by the *Wigner map*,
$$
\bbox[yellow]{ g(x,p) =\frac{\hbar}{2\pi} \int d\tau  d\sigma ~ e^{i(\tau p + \sigma x)} 
\hbox{Tr}\left ( 
e^{-i(\tau {\mathfrak p} + \sigma {\mathfrak x})} {\mathfrak G} \right )    \phantom{baronsamedi}
 \\ 
=\hbar    \int dy~ e^{-iyp} \left \langle x +\frac{\hbar}{2}y 
\right | {\mathfrak G}({\mathfrak x},{\mathfrak p}) 
\left | x-\frac{\hbar}{2}y \right \rangle  } ~~,
$$
since the above trace, in the coordinate representation,
$\exp (i \tau {\mathfrak p})|x\rangle=|x-\hbar \tau\rangle$, reduces to
$$
\int dz ~ e^{i\tau  \sigma \hbar /2 }  \langle z | 
e^{-i\sigma {\mathfrak x} }   e^{-i \tau {\mathfrak p}} {\mathfrak G} 
| z \rangle = \int dz  e^{i\sigma (\tau\hbar /2-z)}  
\langle z -\hbar \tau | {\mathfrak G} | z \rangle . 
$$

Equivalently, the c-number integral kernel of the operator amounts
to
$$
\langle x | {\mathfrak G} | y \rangle =
\int\! \frac{dp}{2\pi\hbar} ~ \exp\left( i p {(x-y)\over \hbar} 
\right ) ~ g\left( {x+y\over 2}, p\right) .     
$$

Now, in general, *g* is not quite "classical": it may well involve $\hbar$. If you are seeking a "classical limit" phase-space expression, take $\hbar\to 0$ on this image of the map, very-very carefully.

Predictably, the Wigner map of $[{\mathfrak G}, {\mathfrak F}   ]/i\hbar  $ in this limit is $\{ g,f\}$ as in Dirac's celebrated PhD thesis.

The inverse map to this Wigner map is the *Weyl map*, [equation (134) here](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf), or, else, [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform).

Comment: Prof, to reach an understanding of this, would you suggest I read up on Weyl Correspondance ?